# Adding new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to insert a new column in Pandas where its name comes from a variable?

Help very much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: How about `var = "foo" df[var] = 0`?

Comment: @295 does the below solution answer your question?

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav, Question answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below:

```
varA = 'sometext'
df[varA] = 'testValue'
```

This will add column `sometext` with data `testValue`